# Prefab in unity appears in a wrong location when drag and dropped

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I've created a prefab of a trophy in unity. But when i drag and drop prefab to the scene, it appears in the wrong location. You can see at the photo where i drop it(red circle), and where it appears(green arrow).

[image: Screenshot of unity]

Same happens when i instantiate it with a script. it appears righter and higher than i click.

Comment: your sprite child(s) nested under `Trophy` seem to have a local offset ... You can see the pivot (circle next to your red area) where the prefab is actually placed

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is an animation in your prefab.
Make sure no coordinate points are registered in this animation clip.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there is an animation on the trophy. I think what happened was you moved the prefab with recording toggled on and thus, the outcome would be like that. All you have to do is edit the prefab's animation and at the start of the animation, set the position to 0 on all axis. If the problem is still there, check the script, maybe there's something wrong with that? Also if you're still stuck, edit your post with the script. And when I say 'the script' I mean the script that instantiates the prefab.

I hope this helps in some way! :D

Comment: Hi. I've deleted the animation from the trophy, but it still behaves the same way. Are there any other possible reasons for that?

Comment: Can I please see the script that instantiates the trophy? Maybe I can spot if something's wrong.